# Simple Button Array doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, button

I need to create a simple Minesweeper Game at school. I want to make a JButton-Array for an easy use. However it doesn't work! I fell like i've searched the whole internet for a solution! Can you help me maybe? Here's the code:

```
public class Minesweeper extends Applet {

    public void init() {

        //Frameinitialiing

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Minesweeper");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        int width = 800;
        frame.setSize(width, width);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocation(0,0);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        //Game

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(panel);


        //Buttons

        int w = 80;

        JButton[][] button = new JButton[10][10];
        for (int i = 1; i == 9 ; i++ ) {

            for (int j = 1; j == 9 ; j++ ) {

                button[i][j].setBounds(i*80 , j*80 , w , w);
                this.add(button[i][j]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work and what did you try to solve it?

Comment: I'm sure you get an error message, which and what did you already do yourself (Solution is quite simple!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has lots of places that needs to be changed. But I have changed them for you:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Minesweeper");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    int width = 800;
    frame.setSize(width, width);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocation(0,0);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    int w = 80;

    JButton[][] button = new JButton[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++ ) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 10 ; j++ ) {
            button[i][j]  = new JButton();
            button[i][j].setBounds(i*80 , j*80 , w , w);
            frame.add(button[i][j]);

        }
    }
```

First of all, the for loop is wrong. You seemed to have messed up the numbers. The two loops should both be `= 0` and `< 10`. Also, I removed these three lines:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    frame.add(panel);
```

You forgot the initialize the buttons using `new JButton()`, so I did it for you.

Finally, it is `frame.add(button[i][j])` instead of `this.add(button[i][j])`.

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However, this is what i see now: https://postimg.org/image/v3fkocdiz/ - the buttons appear when i go over their location....

Comment: Hmm... That is weird. Somehow I didn't get that kind of thing. Maybe this is something to do with the inner workings of JFrame layouts. You can always search on the internet or ask another question. I recommend you to not use coordinates. Instead, use one of the layouts that awt provided, like `FlowLayout`. @Peaq

Comment: Thanks, i just tweaked the frame width and it worked :D!